# How to delete google play?

Tags: google-play-store

I want to disable or delete google play store (I don't want the person who has access to the device to install any apps, and I want to free up some space while I'm at it).

I have root. Where are the files stored (such as the apk, odex)?

Is it in /system/app?

Answer (score 0):

Use titanium backup, which lets you disable/remove apps like that. Or, flash a new rom that doesn't include gapps, download a gapps package and remove the Play Store, then flash that modified package.

Comment: Do I have to get rid of all gapps to remove google play? Can I first install google maps and then remove google play?

Comment: You shouldn't have to remove everything just to disable the one app. Google Maps? Sorry, I can't really follow haha. Should be a simple task to use an app such as Titanium Backup to disable/remove the Play Store by itself. If you ever do want to put it back on your device you can always download and install the apk from here: 
http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/13/download-latest-google-play-store-4-6-16-with-new-require-password-option-tweaked-ui-forced-self-update-and-more/ (I believe that is the latest version of the store, but I may be wrong).